# Content Spinning using PHP?

Tags: php, string, spinning

Can anyone please help me? Say if I had [this text](http://tehwebz.com/spinning.txt) or a smaller section stored in a variable, how can I randomise the words in the '{ }' ?
For example, the first one is "{important|essential|crucial|critical|vital|significant}" how can I make PHP choose one of those words randomly and then echo it? Thanks for helping me. :)

Comment: take a look at preg_replace_callback.

Comment: Smells like a interview question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://webarto.com/62/random-sentence-spinning-function

```
function get_random($matches)
{
    $rand = array_rand($split = explode("|", $matches[1]));
    return $split[$rand];
}

function show_randomized($str)
{
    $new_str = preg_replace_callback('/\{([^{}]*)\}/im', "get_random", $str);
    if ($new_str !== $str) $str = show_randomized($new_str);
    return $str;
}
```

Applied on your text file... http://ideone.com/rkuf6

Answer (score 2):

- strip off initial and ending curly braces, you can use `trim()`
- explode the resulting string on `|` using `explode()`
- use `array_rand()` for the array you had in last step

Comment: or use the preg_replace_callback :(

Comment: maybe something like this http://webarto.com/11/random-sentence-spinning, but it will not work on recursive brackets.

Comment: Looks bullet proof to me, I find myself very weak at regular expressions and love to use lesser expensive routines, so quickly came up with my simple idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Will not work with nested({a|x {b|c} y|z})!

```
function doStuff($from){
    $to="";
    while(($pos=strpos($from,'{'))!==false){
        $to.=substr($from,0,$pos);
        $from=substr($from,$pos);
        $closepos=strpos($from,'}');
        $arr=explode('|',substr($from,1,$closepos-1));
        $to.=$arr[array_rand($arr)];
        $from=substr($from,$closepos+1);
    }
    return $to.$from;
}
```

Comment: It won't work on `{rotate {quickly|fast} and {random|accidental}|spin and be random}`